# Is there a way to make powershell log to a text file even if the -whatif property is set?

Tags: powershell

Running the powershell script below will provide console output when ran but it will not write to the output file.  I believe this is because the -Whatif property is set.  Is there a way to make powershell write to the console and output file if the -Whatif property is set?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$targetFolder\*" -File | Remove-Item -WhatIf -Force -Verbose *> "C:\Users\HKM\Desktop\Test\Logs.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -WhatIf parameter generates writes to the host, which you cannot redirect.

One option might be to use `Start-Transcript Logfile.txt` to catch the additional output.

Comment: Just FYI for future people: There is a currently open issue on GH that pre-dates this question (maybe one day it'll be implemented): https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9870